# Unable update and delete database views in silverlight business application

Tags: silverlight-4.0

In silverlight buspliiness apcation for updating database domain context is updated but what should I do when I want to update and delete record from original table.

Answer (score 0):

You must call DomainContext.SubmitChanges() if you mean that situation.

Comment: but that will update my database view.I want to update original table

Comment: updating original table is server side function. You must create functions for updating and deleting in your domain.

Comment: How to call these functions e.g.Update and Delete in xaml wich I have created in domain

Comment: in xaml? its poor decision. in xaml you can tie data from context, but all data operations you must write in background code

Comment: sorry!! in xaml.cs. I tried to use domainContext.SubmitChanges(); but unable to update.

Comment: I'm using database view to display data and when I Add,Update and delete records that should be handled with original table. right??

Comment: I'm using database view to display data and when I Add,Update and delete records that should be handled with original table. right?? According to me when I write DomainContext.submitchanges() to update a record, that will update view not original table. So to update original table you told that create functions in domain and call to xaml.cs. Ok? again,Domain have readymade functions for Insert,update and delete. But not available to call in xaml.cs. So my question is how to call these functions in xaml.cs

Comment: these function will be called when you call SubmitChanges. example: public void UpdateZonePolygon(ZonePolygon currentZonePolygon)
        {
            this.ObjectContext.ZonePolygons.AttachAsModified(currentZonePolygon, this.ChangeSet.GetOriginal(currentZonePolygon));
        }

        public void DeleteZonePolygon(ZonePolygon zonePolygon)
        {
            if ((zonePolygon.EntityState == EntityState.Detached))
            {
                this.ObjectContext.ZonePolygons.Attach(zonePolygon);
            }
            this.ObjectContext.ZonePolygons.DeleteObject(zonePolygon);
        }

Comment: I have those finctions in Domain but how to call in xaml.cs

Comment: I have those finctions in Domain but how to call in xaml.cs. My functions are 
public void UpdatePortfolio(Portfolio currentPortfolio){       this.ObjectContext.Portfolios.AttachAsModified(currentPortfolio, this.ChangeSet.GetOriginal(currentPortfolio));}
public void DeletePortfolio(Portfolio portfolio){
if ((portfolio.EntityState == EntityState.Detached)){
this.ObjectContext.Portfolios.Attach(portfolio);}
this.ObjectContext.Portfolios.DeleteObject(portfolio);}

Comment: for deletion you must delete entity from collection of entities in domain context and then call SubmitChanges. if all ok, delete function in domain class will be called without need of direct call. For update just get entie from collection, change propertie and submitchanges. For insert you must add to collection and also submitchanges.

Comment: delete: private void DeleteButton_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var join = JoinsDataGrid.SelectedItem as UsageTypeZoneSymbolJoin;
            if (join != null)
            {
                context.UsageTypeZoneSymbolJoins.Remove(join);
            }
            BusyInd.IsBusy = true;
            Action<SubmitOperation> submitAction = new Action<SubmitOperation>(DeleteCompleted);
            context.SubmitChanges(submitAction, join);
        }

Comment: insert:  var join = new UsageTypeZoneSymbolJoin();
            join.UsageType = UsageTypeAutoComplete.SelectedItem as UsageType;
            join.ZoneSymbol = SymbolCombo.SelectedItem as ZoneSymbol;
            join.iType = (int)JoinType.Value;
            context.UsageTypeZoneSymbolJoins.Add(join);

            BusyInd.IsBusy = true;
            Action<SubmitOperation> submitAction = new Action<SubmitOperation>(AddCompleted);
            context.SubmitChanges(submitAction, join);

Comment: In delete code I got exception at line  con.Occupants.Remove(DelOccup); My delete btn code is        private void Deletebtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
var DelOccup = view_OccupantsDataGrid.SelectedItem as View_Occupants;
if (DelOccup != null)
{ con.Occupants.Remove(DelOccup);
}
BusyIndicator bz = new BusyIndicator();
bz.IsBusy = true;
Action<SubmitOperation> submitAction = new Action<SubmitOperation>(DeleteCompleted);
con.SubmitChanges(submitAction, DelOccup);                        
}

Comment: what kind of exception? may be DelOccup not exist in Occupants collection?

Comment: Exception is:EntitySet of type 'BusinessApplication3.Web.Models.Occupant' cannot contain instances of Type 'BusinessApplication3.Web.Models.View_Occupants'.
Parameter name: entity

Comment: all information is in exception. you'v use view instead of entity

Comment: So what should i do to delete record from entity

Comment: you should delete entity, not entity view, from context collection

Comment: when I take selected item from datagrid what type of cast should I use,entity or entity view(both are not working)

Comment: i dont know, its hard to explain unless you are trying to understand yourself